# line feed inside row in column with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, linefeed

are there any way in pandas to separate data inside a row in a column? row have multiple data,  I mean, I group by col1 and the result is that I have a df like that:

```
    col1   Col2
0   1      abc,def,ghi
1   2      xyz,asd

and desired output would be:

    Col1    Col2
 0  1       abc
            def
            ghi
 1  2       xyz
            asd
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.split` and `explode`:

```
print (df.assign(Col2=df["Col2"].str.split(","))
         .explode("Col2"))

   col1 Col2
0     1  abc
0     1  def
0     1  ghi
1     2  xyz
1     2  asd
```